# Javascript date filter to DataTable using single textbox with calendar selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, datatable

Javascript  Date filter to DataTable using single textbox with calendar selection.
Below is my datatable and script code.

```
 <table id="datatable" class="table table-bordered table-striped dataTable" style="width: 100%">
      <thead>
      <tr>
          <th style="width: 300px;">SDMSID</th>
          <th style="width: 300px;">Asessor</th>
          <th style="width: 300px;">Sector</th>
          <th style="width: 300px;">Job Role</th>
          <th style="width: 300px;">State</th>
          <th style="width: 300px;">City</th>
          <th style="width: 300px;">Assessment Date</th>
          <th style="width: 300px;">Batch Status</th>
          <th>Edit Assessor</th>
          <th>Add Candidates</th>
          <th>Manage Batch</th>

       </tr>
       </thead>
    </table>
```

I used below script to fill data-table

```
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

     <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

   function loadgrid() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'Getdropdowns.asmx/filreschedulebatchgrid',
                method: 'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#datatable").dataTable().fnDestroy()
                    $('#datatable').dataTable({
                        responsive: true,
                        paging: false,
                        sort: true,
                        searching: true,
                        processing: true,
                        destroy: true,
                        data: data,
                        aaSorting: [],

                        columns: [

                            { 'data': 'SDMSId' },
                            { 'data': 'UserName' },
                            { 'data': 'SectorFullName' },
                            { 'data': 'JobRoleFullName' },
                            { 'data': 'State' },
                            { 'data': 'City' },
                            {
                                'data': 'AssessmentStartDate',
                                'render': function (Assessment_Date) {
                                    var date = new Date(Assessment_Date);
                                    var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
                                    return (month.length > 1 ? month : "0" + month) + "/" + date.getDate() + "/" + date.getFullYear();
                                }
                            },
                              { 'data': 'DisplayName' },

                         {
                             'data': 'BatchId',
                             'sortable': false,
                             'searchable': false,
                             'render': function (BatchId) {

                                 return '<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1" class="editor_edit btn btn-warning btn-xs" id=' + BatchId + ' ><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>';
                             }
                         },
                         {
                             'data': 'BatchId',
                             'sortable': false,
                             'searchable': false,
                             'render': function (BatchId) {

                                 return '<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" style="color: white;" data-target="#myModal2" class="editor_add btn btn-warning btn-xs" id=' + BatchId + ' ><i class="fa fa-user-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>';

                                 //'<input id=' + BatchId + ' type="button" onserverclick="foo_OnClick" />';


                             }
                         },
                         {
                             'data': 'BatchId',
                             'sortable': false,
                             'searchable': false,
                             'render': function (BatchId) {

                                 return '<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" style="color: white;" data-target="#myModal3" class="editor_manage btn btn-warning btn-xs" id=' + BatchId + ' ><i class="fa fa-file" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>';
                             }
                         }
                        ]
                    });
                }
            });
        };
         });
```

I tried below example not working and i need some easy way to achieve  this filter.

http://plnkr.co/edit/8z7cojpJoCSJXRn9prNj?p=preview

Please suggest how to achieve single data filter with calendar thank you in advance.

Comment: you forgot to post the question ?

Comment: where is the question?

Comment: what problem do you have?

Comment: what errors do you have?

Comment: what is the behavior you expect?

Comment: where do you call the `loadgrid` function?

Comment: these are question , you see the little ? sign at the end of the sentence?

Comment: dear madalinivascu i given link above need like that date filter to datatable. @madalinivascu

Comment: at least answer **where do you call the `loadgrid` function?**

Comment: please do not confuse me, data table filling correctly, just tell me date filter with new textbox. @madalinivascu

Comment: I can not post all javascript code, i use some places loadgrid function and please tell me the what i need. @madalinivascu

Comment: dear did you understand my question. @madalinivascu

Comment: Are you there?.@madalinivascu

Answer (score 0):

Based on the example you provided, to achieve a filter based on a date input you need to:

1) Include the date picker within your HTML:

```
<p id="date_filter">
    <span id="date-label-from" class="date-label">From: </span><input class="date_range_filter date" type="text" id="datepicker_from" />    
</p>
```

2) Include the following field within your datatable:

```
"sSearch": "Filter Data"
```

3) When creating your table, assign it to a variable, for example:

```
var oTable = $('#datatable').dataTable({
              your code goes here...
              });
```

4) Assign the datepicker functionality to your HTML input element:

```
    $("#datepicker_from").datepicker({
        showOn: "button",
       "onSelect": function(date) {
            minDateFilter = new Date(date).getTime();
            oTable.fnDraw();
        }
      }).keyup(function() {
          minDateFilter = new Date(this.value).getTime();
          oTable.fnDraw();
      });
  });
```

More information about Jquery's datepicker functionality can be found here: 
http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: @mazhar All I have done is taken code snippets from the plnkr link you provided to try and explain how the example code is working and how you can use it to add the same functionality to your own code. I simplified the code a bit to help explain things: http://plnkr.co/edit/YaJuuBV6kB2YPiM7YLaQ?p=preview

Comment: @mazhar Any further help required?